# Environment variable set but HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName not updated

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Am running .net core 2.2 and hosting asp.net core within a windows service.
eg.  see this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

I set the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to "Dev"

Just to confirm, within my launchsettings.json

```
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT ": "Dev"
  }
```

[image]

When starting up the value of HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName is not updated and still has "Production" which is default.  Why is it not "Dev"?

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)                
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
            logging.AddEventLog();
        })
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {

            // Configure the app here.
            var env = context.HostingEnvironment;
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                              .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

}

Comment: You mean like a system level environment var?  See above screenshot, I have the environment var set only in the IDE.

Comment: Check [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2#environment-based-startup-class-and-methods). The docs explain that .NET Core recognized just three values for that environment variable, Development, Staging and Production. It could be that `EnvironmentName` is only set when the contents of the environment variable are recognized

Comment: The docs also explain that this setting is used to control several debugging features. The runtime has no idea what `Dev` means so the correct behavior would be to default to production - or throw.

Comment: We have environments like QA and UAT and those are set correctly.

Comment: The framework supports setting it to any value, but the default WebHost builder will only include user secrets in the "Development" environment by default, so that won't work if yours is something else. But you can call your environments anything and add your own extension methods to check for your environments.

Comment: Hopefully it's just a typo, but you've got a trailing space in `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT ` in your `launchSettings.json`.

Comment: @Kirk - oh good grief, that was it!  Good catch.  I thought I was going nuts

Comment: I've added ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development in system environment variables. But still, I'm getting Production as Environment name from hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName. Am i missing anything here?

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 7):

I spent quite a while trying to work out the best thing for me to do in this situation.

I ended up taking the code from Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.CreateDefaultBuilder and adding the .UseEnvironment extension on the builder.

```
            builder.UseEnvironment(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Development");
```

I default to Development rather than the generally preferred Production, but that was personal preference.

It is limited and if you want to be clever and check for commandline arguments etc and so forth, feel free. It's a place to start.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateDefaultBuilder(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new HostBuilder();

    // This line has been added to read the environment variable.
    builder.UseEnvironment(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Development");

    builder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
    builder.ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
    {
        config.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "DOTNET_");
        if (args != null)
        {
            config.AddCommandLine(args);
        }
    });

    builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
    {
        var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

        if (env.IsDevelopment() && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(env.ApplicationName))
        {
            var appAssembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(env.ApplicationName));
            if (appAssembly != null)
            {
                config.AddUserSecrets(appAssembly, optional: true);
            }
        }

        config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

        if (args != null)
        {
            config.AddCommandLine(args);
        }
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
    {
        var isWindows = RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows);

        // IMPORTANT: This needs to be added *before* configuration is loaded, this lets
        // the defaults be overridden by the configuration.
        if (isWindows)
        {
            // Default the EventLogLoggerProvider to warning or above
            logging.AddFilter<EventLogLoggerProvider>(level => level >= Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Warning);
        }

        logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        logging.AddConsole();
        logging.AddDebug();
        logging.AddEventSourceLogger();

        if (isWindows)
        {
            // Add the EventLogLoggerProvider on windows machines
            logging.AddEventLog();
        }
    })
    .UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
    {
        var isDevelopment = context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
        options.ValidateScopes = isDevelopment;
        options.ValidateOnBuild = isDevelopment;
    });

    return builder;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kept coming back to this question when a .NET project wouldn't build correctly. It should be looking for `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`. I found it works best just to export all versions of environment that could be used when looking for "environment” in .NET.

```
context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName;
```

So I export `ENVIRONMENT`, `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`, `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` all as the environment you are trying to make. So in this case all set to "dev".